# Move last <li> element to bottom of container with the rest centered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get my menu centered using flexbox centering in the middle of the bar while the last element is pushed to the bottom of the container.

Here is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/815/).

I've tried with `align-self flex-end` with no success and

```
li:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

That aligns my the last element to the bottom but pushes the rest of the items to the other end of the container.

Comment: Remove the `padding, the last `<li>` have the same `padding` as the others`

Comment: If you add `li:first-child { margin-top: auto; }` it will work though

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: wow, thanks dunno how I missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another empty `<li>` at the beginning of the list and give him the `flex-grow:1` property, and then set it to the last `li` as well. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/817/)

It might work without an extra element, just set the first `li` to have `flex-grow:1`. [Second example here](http://jsfiddle.net/k2R3G/818/)

Note that you'll have to keep your text inside the first element aligned to the bottom.